# PHP Syntax error, please review my code, I don't need a link to mindlessly view endless code

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've searched many stackoverflow questions and the provided links like "PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them ?"

Can anyone review my section of code and tell me what my error is? I'm pulling my hair-out on this.

This is a simple school project. I don't care to change the code to use mysqli

> Error: syntax error , unexpected "", expecting identifier (t_string)
>   or variable (t_variable) or number (t_num_string)

Thanks!

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        form{
            width: 400px;
            height: 600px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        span{
            display: block;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    // A simple PHP script demonstrating how to connect to MySQL.
    // Provides a form for adding, and deleting a student record to the database

    $servername = getenv('IP');
    $username = getenv('JSMITH');
    $password = "1234";
    $database = "JSMITH";
    $dbport = 3306;

    // Create connection
    $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $dbport);

    // Check connection
    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully (".$db->host_info.")";

    $thisPHP = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    echo <<<EOE
    <form action="$thisPHP" method="POST">
        Name:</span>
        <input type="text" name="Name"><br>

        <span>Address:</span>
        <input type="text" name="Address"><br>

        <span>Phone:</span>
        <input type="number" name="Phone_number"><br>

        <span>Email:</span>
        <input type="text" name="Email">

        <span>Avaliability:</span>
        <input type="radio" name="Avaliable" value="Now">Now: (&lt; 1 Month) <br>
        <input type="radio" name="Avaliable" value="Soon" >Soon: (1-3 months)<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Avaliable" value="Exploring">Upcoming: (3+ months)<br>


        <span>Company:</span>
        <input type="text" name="Company"><br>

        <span>Job:</span>
        <input type="text" name="Job"><br>

        <span>Description:</span>
        <input type="text" name="Description"><br>

        <span>Skills</span>
        <select name="Skill">
            <option value="SQL">SQL</option>
            <option value="Java">Java</option>
            <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
            <option value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
            <option value="C++">C++</option>
            <option value="C#">C#</option>
            <option value="XML">XML</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
            <option value="Python">Python</option>
            <option value="PHP">PHP</option>

        </select>

        <span>Experience:</span>
        <select name="Period">
        <option value="0" >0</option>
        <option value="1-3">1-3</option>
        <option value="3-5">3-5</option>
        <option value="5-10">5-10</option>
        <option value="10+">10+</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <span>Position:</span>
        <input type="radio" name="Position" value="Team-Member" >Team-Member<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Position" value="Team Leader">Team Leader<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Position" value="Executive">Executive<br>
        <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add"><br>

    </form>  
EOT;

    // Start executing the script
    {
    $Name = $_POST["Name"];
    $Address = $_POST["Address"];
    $Phone = $_POST["Phone"];
    $Email = $_POST["Email"];
    $Availability = $_POST['Availability'];
    $Company = $_POST["Company Name"];
    $Job = $_POST['Job Title'];
    $description = $_POST['Description'];
    $Skill = $_POST['Skill'];
    $Period = $_POST['Period'];
    $Position = $_POST['Position'];
    $Update=$_POST["Update"];

 if(!empty($Name)){
    $sql="INSERT INTO employee(Name, Address, Phone, Email, Availability, Company Name, Job Title, Description, Skill, Period, Position) 
    VALUES ('$Name','$Address','$Phone','$Email','$Avaliabilty','$Company','$Job','$Description','$Period','$Skill','$Position')";
    if($db->query($sql) == TRUE){
        echo ("Record added");
    }


}
 if (isset($Update)){
    $sql="UPDATE employee SET Address='$Address',Phone='$Phone',Email='$Email',Availability='$Availability',Company='$Company',Job='$Job',Description='$Description',Skill = '$Skill',Period='$Period',Position='$Position' WHERE Name='$Name' ";
    $db->query($sql);

  }
    $db->close();
?>
```

Comment: please show us the whole code!

Comment: Will do! updating now

Comment: Uploaded complete code

Comment: Simple project that I need to take user information. Enter the information into a form. send that to a sql file. and allow the user to edit or delete the form submitted data

Comment: You haven't started `<?php` above `$Name = $_POST["Name"];` . Maybe it's the error!

Comment: I never closed the original <?php from the beginning of the file tho? :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code I have corrected the form and removed the `{' which was causing the error

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
            <style>
                form{
                    width: 400px;
                    height: 600px;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    display: block;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
                span{
                    display: block;
                }

            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        <?php
            // A simple PHP script demonstrating how to connect to MySQL.
            // Provides a form for adding, and deleting a student record to the database

            $servername = getenv('IP');
            $username = getenv('JSMITH');
            $password = "1234";
            $database = "JSMITH";
            $dbport = "3306";

            // Create connection
            $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $dbport);

            // Check connection
            if ($db->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
            } 
            echo "Connected successfully (".$db->host_info.")";

            $thisPHP = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        ?>
            <form action="$thisPHP" method="POST">
                Name:</span>
                <input type="text" name="Name"><br>

                <span>Address:</span>
                <input type="text" name="Address"><br>

                <span>Phone:</span>
                <input type="number" name="Phone_number"><br>

                <span>Email:</span>
                <input type="text" name="Email">

                <span>Avaliability:</span>
                <input type="radio" name="Avaliable" value="Now">Now: (&lt; 1 Month) <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Avaliable" value="Soon" >Soon: (1-3 months)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="Avaliable" value="Exploring">Upcoming: (3+ months)<br>


                <span>Company:</span>
                <input type="text" name="Company"><br>

                <span>Job:</span>
                <input type="text" name="Job"><br>

                <span>Description:</span>
                <input type="text" name="Description"><br>

                <span>Skills</span>
                <select name="Skill">
                    <option value="SQL">SQL</option>
                    <option value="Java">Java</option>
                    <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
                    <option value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
                    <option value="C++">C++</option>
                    <option value="C#">C#</option>
                    <option value="XML">XML</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
                    <option value="Python">Python</option>
                    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>

                </select>

                <span>Experience:</span>
                <select name="Period">
                <option value="0" >0</option>
                <option value="1-3">1-3</option>
                <option value="3-5">3-5</option>
                <option value="5-10">5-10</option>
                <option value="10+">10+</option>
                </select>
                <br>

                <span>Position:</span>
                <input type="radio" name="Position" value="Team-Member" >Team-Member<br>
                <input type="radio" name="Position" value="Team Leader">Team Leader<br>
                <input type="radio" name="Position" value="Executive">Executive<br>
                <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add"><br>

            </form>  
        <?php

            // Start executing the script
            if (!empty($_POST))
            {
            $Name = $_POST["Name"];
            $Address = $_POST["Address"];
            $Phone = $_POST["Phone"];
            $Email = $_POST["Email"];
            $Availability = $_POST['Availability'];
            $Company = $_POST["Company Name"];
            $Job = $_POST['Job Title'];
            $description = $_POST['Description'];
            $Skill = $_POST['Skill'];
            $Period = $_POST['Period'];
            $Position = $_POST['Position'];
            $Update=$_POST["Update"];

         if(!empty($Name)){
            $sql="INSERT INTO employee(Name, Address, Phone, Email, Availability, Company Name, Job Title, Description, Skill, Period, Position) 
            VALUES ('$Name','$Address','$Phone','$Email','$Avaliabilty','$Company','$Job','$Description','$Period','$Skill','$Position')";
            if($db->query($sql) == TRUE){
                echo ("Record added");
            }


        }
         if (isset($Update)){
            $sql="UPDATE employee SET Address='$Address',Phone='$Phone',Email='$Email',Availability='$Availability',Company='$Company',Job='$Job',Description='$Description',Skill = '$Skill',Period='$Period',Position='$Position' WHERE Name='$Name' ";
            $db->query($sql);

          }

            $db->close();
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! When I try an run this along side with my local database file I receive an "The requested URL /$thisPHP was not found on this server." error when I submit the data, any idea?

Comment: it means `action="$thisPHP"` is not working . replace it with `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" `

Answer (score 0):

add `?>` before `<form action="$thisPHP" method="POST">` and add `<?php` before the line `// Start executing the script` and check what happens!

Comment: don't forget to add `<?php echo $thisPHP; ?>` in form action and replace all the variables like that!

Comment: I'm confused, can you give me an example of that? :o

Comment: Brother, Already it looks like your code is not completely written by you. I am trying to give you the simplest solution and you can't understand that. I can't debug whole code for you. I told you about your mistake and you can now solve it.

Comment: I'm in my first php class. Just learning the hard way. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Great! One quick tip: You can't write html code between `<?php` and `?>` . :)